# UML Activity Diagram: Subactivity/Call Acivity Action (Edraw Max)

Tags: uml, activity-diagram, subactivity

Is the Subactivity/Call Acivity Action actually part of the language specification? According to [this](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/activity-diagrams-reference.html) source it's not:

> Call activity action is indicated by a rake-style symbol within the action symbol. Note, that though UML 2.4 specification provides this notation, there is no official call activity action in the UML specification.

However one can find many examples where the rake symbol is used and discussed. Also, I cannot find the symbol within 'Edraw Max'. Since I'm comparing the UML Activity Diagram to another notation in terms of what one can and cannot do, it's important that I stick to the specification.

If it is part of the specification, can anyone tell me where to find it in Edraw Max?

Answer (score 1):

I did not check with 2.4, but the recent 2.5 specs describes it in chapter **16.3.4.1 Call Behavior Actions** on p. 452:

> ... The call of an Activity is indicated by placing a rake-style symbol within the Action symbol (see Figure 16.15, left). The rake resembles a miniature hierarchy, indicating that this invocation starts another Activity that represents a further decomposition ...

I can't help with EDraw, but Enterprise Architect does have this notation since a long time. You should use a modeling rather than a drawing tool to create UML models.

Answer (score 0):

The web site you linked to is not quite correct in its assertion. What has been part of the UML specification (as far back as I can remember) is `CallBehaviorAction`. Since an `Activity` is a kind of `Behavior`, the `CallBehaviorAction` is what you use to invoke an `Activity`. There is no `CallActivityAction` because none is needed. The `CallBehaviorAction` has that rake icon.